# OSMIUM deleted column conflict with OSM

Tags: python, openstreetmap, osmium

The following code used to extract the data from a history file.

```
import osmium

class CounterHandler(osmium.SimpleHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        osmium.SimpleHandler.__init__(self)
        self.num_ways = 0
        self.elemtimeline = []
        
     
    def way(self, n):
        self.elemtimeline.append([n.id,
                                  n.version,
                                  n.visible,
                                  pd.Timestamp(n.timestamp),
                                  n.uid,
                                  n.changeset,
                                  n.deleted])
        self.num_ways += 1

h = CounterHandler()

h.apply_file("test.osm.pbf")
colnames = ['id', 'version', 'visible', 'ts', 'uid', 'chgset','deleted']

elements = pd.DataFrame(h.elemtimeline, columns=colnames)
elements.head(10)
```

The output table:

[image]

When this is checked on `OSM` https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/30046162 it shows that this is deleted over 9 years ago.

[image]

However in the table the `deleted` column shows `False`. Why is the conflict? Or is there a way to find the deleted objects from the history file?

Comment: To me it seems that this should work. At least, the following example from pyosmium shows similar usage of the visible/deleted flag: https://github.com/osmcode/pyosmium/blob/master/examples/osm_diff_stats.py
Are you sure that the _visible_ flag hasn't been stripped from the `test.osm.pbf` file? Did you try to test it with a fresh `osh.pbf` file (e.g. Liechtenstein from geofabrik: http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/liechtenstein.html)?